# delete rsnapshot directories

Tags: backup, debian-jessie, rsnapshot

Looking to move from rsnapshot backups to something like backupninja. I'm having trouble finding a definitive answer on how to delete the rsnapshot backups.

From what I understand many of the files are hard links and not actual copies.

How can I delete `/mnt/disk1/backups/*` (daily.0, weekly.0, etc) without harming the original files?

Is it simply `rm /mnt/disk1/backups/* -R`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right about backup files being hard links and it is safe to just delete the backup directory.

Hard links are just pointers, so if a file have two hard links then the space  occupied by this file will only be reclaimed by OS when both links are deleted.